# How to remove new line characters from data rows

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file as below

```
Emp1|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|Address|Pincode|PhoneNumber
1234|FirstName1|MiddleName2|LastName3| Add1 || ADD2|123|000000000
2345|FirstName2|MiddleName3|LastName4|
Add1 || ADD2|
 234|000000000
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Emp1|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|Address|Pincode|PhoneNumber
1234|FirstName1|MiddleName2|LastName3| Add1 || ADD2|123|000000000
2345|FirstName2|MiddleName3|LastName4| Add1 || ADD2|234|000000000
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This Q has been asked (and answered) numerous times. Try searching for `[awk] remove new lines csv`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not so much *How to remove new line characters*, but when to remove them. Fortunately, the lines which need to be joined with the following line can be determined by the trailing `|`. An appropriate `sed`command is:

```
sed ':0;/|$/{N;s/\n//;b0}'
```

- `:0` - label at beginning of script
- `/|$/` - address lines ending with `|`
- `N` - append next line of input
- `s/\n//` - delete the embedded newline
- `b0` - branch to beginning of script (to join more lines)